# Pymongo aggregation with project

Tags: pymongo

I have a very basic question,

what's the Pymongo equivalent of

```
select name, surname, CONCAT(name, surname)
from db
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the mongo db collection, to db object. it works

```
concat_results = db.aggregate(
   [
      { "$project": { "NewFieldName": { "$concat": [ "$name", "$surname" ] } ,"name":True,"name":surname} }
   ]
);

for concat_result in concat_results:
    print("name":concat_result["name"],"surname":concat_result["name"],"NewFieldName":concat_result["NewFieldName"])
```